# Jira query for comments with specific text

Tags: syntax, jira

How do you look for jira tickets with comments containing two text strings with many possible strings in between the two.  For example, I want to search for tickets with a comment containing a name "Smith" and later in the comment, the word "fixed".

Comment: Search how? In the browser? Using the REST API? What have you tried?

Comment: In the browser where you set up a query.  I've been trying various text strings to search the name field for these strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search query would look like this:

`comment ~ 'Smith fixed'`